# Moonbase parachain collator not producing blocks using zombienet

Tags: wasm, parachain-collator, zombienet, moonbeam

I am trying to run `zombienet` tests with 2 polkadot relay chain nodes and 1 parachain collator running the moonbeam binary. The test config is as follows: `test.toml`

```rust
[settings]
timeout = 1000

[relaychain]
default_command = "polkadot"
default_args = [ "-lparachain=debug" ]

[relaychain.default_resources]
limits = { memory = "4G", cpu = "2" }
requests = { memory = "2G", cpu = "1" }

chain = "rococo-local"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"
  args = [ "--alice", "-lparachain=debug,runtime=debug" ]

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  args = [ "--bob", "-lparachain=debug,runtime=debug"]

[[parachains]]
id = 1282
genesis_wasm_path="./wasm/orig.wasm.hex"
chain = "moonbase-local"

  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  command = "moonbeam"
  prometheus_prefix = "moonbeam_substrate"
  args = ["-lparachain=debug"]

[types.Header]
number = "u64"
parent_hash = "Hash"
post_state = "Hash"
```

the `test.zndsl` is:

```js
Description: PVF code size
Network: ./0001-parachains-pvf-code-size-good.toml
Creds: config

# Check authority status.
alice: reports node_roles is 4

# Ensure parachains are registered.
alice: parachain 1282 is registered within 60 seconds

# Ensure parachains made progress.
# We have a different hard limit for the candidate max code size in different host implementations
# so we can't check for a specific value here. we only ensure that block production continued

alice: parachain 1282 block height is at least 10 within 200 seconds

# Check code size.
# We have a different hard limit for the candidate max code size in different host implementations
# however if the code size is acceptable we should have it put in some metric bucket

# check if we have at least 1 sample, but we should have many more.
alice: reports histogram polkadot_parachain_candidate_validation_code_size has at least 1 samples in buckets ["16384", "32768", "65536", "131072", "262144", "524288", "1048576", "2097152", "4194304", "8388608", "+Inf"] within 30 seconds
```

The WASM is generated using moonbeam `export-genesis-wasm > fetched.wasm` and then I am using [wasm-injector](https://github.com/LimeChain/wasm-injector) to convert it to `./wasm/orig.wasm.hex` (to hexify and potentially uncompress the wasm). The problem is that the unmodified basic example fails with wasm panic code "unreachable".
The test is run using:

> zombienet -p native test test.zndsl

Versions
zombienet 1.3.65

polkadot 0.9.43-ba42b9ce51d

moonbeam 0.32.1-6ed87ceeb65

[image]